# rails 4 simple_form turn off autocomplete at form level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have setup autocomplete in my application and I noticed during testing that it suddenly failed having just been working just moments before. The application returned a **pg error claiming that the employee_id value was null**.

I realized that the browsers native autocomplete had prompted me with the value and therefore the `js` didn't insert the id value into the hidden field.

On checking the Mozilla documentation I see that they recommend turning off autocomplete at the form level. I am using simple_form but can't figure out how to do this.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just pass `autocomplete` option to the `:html` hash:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, html: { autocomplete: 'off' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :country, as: :string %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: without digging too hard, i was passing false and stuff... "off" worked well. thanks Vasily

Comment: This one no longer works, you need the answer below 

Comment: Works for me on Rails 5.1, simple_form 4.0.1

Comment: Works fine for 7.0 simple_form 5.1.0

Answer (score 13):

If you want to turn it off just for one or more attributes instead of the entire form, you can use the option "**input_html**", like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: @form_url) do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.input :password, input_html: { autocomplete: 'off' } %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```